# Failed authentication for Google Sheet and Django running in Apache server

Tags: django, apache, google-sheets, wsgi

I'm implementing a Django application that uses a Google Sheet as database, and is hosted with Apache in a Rocky Linux server.

To test the integration between Django and Google Sheet, I have followed Tom Dekan [Tutorial](https://www.photondesigner.com/articles/django-with-google-sheets-database?ref=yt-XXDiqE4t0xA-django-with-google-sheets-database). And to configure the Django application to run with Apache, I have followed the official [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

However, when I try to access the page, I receive an Internal Server Error. Checking the error logs, I receive the following message:

> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203173 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686] mod_wsgi (pid=150297): Failed to exec Python script file '/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/core/core/wsgi.py'.
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203297 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686] mod_wsgi (pid=150297): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/core/core/wsgi.py'.
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203791 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686] Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203866 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/core/core/wsgi.py", line 22, in <module>
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203876 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]     application = get_wsgi_application()
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203885 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/my_env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203893 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203902 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/my_env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/_*init*_.py", line 19, in setup
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203910 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203919 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/my_env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/_*init*_.py", line 102, in _*getattr*_
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203927 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]     self._setup(name)
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203935 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/my_env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/_*init*_.py", line 89, in _setup
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203943 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203979 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/my_env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/_*init*_.py", line 217, in _*init*_
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203987 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.203996 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/importlib/_*init*_.py", line 127, in import_module
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204003 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204012 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204021 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204030 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204039 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204047 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204060 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204075 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/core/core/settings.py", line 133, in <module>
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204085 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]     GSPREAD_CLIENT = initialize_gspread()  # Starting the gspread client when our server starts speeds things up; it avoids re-authenticating on each request
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204099 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/core/sim/services.py", line 10, in initialize_gspread
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204107 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]     return gspread.service_account_from_dict(get_credentials())  # Note: we could move this to settings to do this once.
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204116 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/my_env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/gspread/auth.py", line 364, in service_account_from_dict
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204124 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]     creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_service_account_info(
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204133 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/my_env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 243, in from_service_account_info
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204141 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]     signer = _service_account_info.from_dict(
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204149 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/my_env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py", line 57, in from_dict
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204157 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]     signer = crypt.RSASigner.from_service_account_info(data)
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204166 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/my_env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/google/auth/crypt/base.py", line 109, in from_service_account_info
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204173 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]     return cls.from_string(
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204187 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/my_env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/google/auth/crypt/_python_rsa.py", line 155, in from_string
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204195 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]     key = _helpers.from_bytes(key)  # PEM expects str in Python 3
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204204 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]   File "/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/my_env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/google/auth/_helpers.py", line 151, in from_bytes
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204211 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686]     raise exceptions.InvalidValue(
>
> [Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204230 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686] google.auth.exceptions.InvalidValue: None could not be converted to unicode

Analyzing the error message, it seems that I'm facing an authentication error. `[Thu Nov 16 11:44:34.204230 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 150297:tid 150433] [remote 143.106.120.120:51686] google.auth.exceptions.InvalidValue: None could not be converted to unicode` This last message, seems to indicate either that I'm not sending any authentication value, or that I'm not receiving a response. Is it correct?

Are there any known problem to run the integration between GSheets and Django with wsgi?

===========================================================================

This is the tree structure of my project

```
.
├── core
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── .env
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── sim
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       └── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── admin.cpython-39.pyc
    │   ├── apps.cpython-39.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
    │   ├── models.cpython-39.pyc
    │   ├── services.cpython-39.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-39.pyc
    │   └── views.cpython-39.pyc
    ├── services.py
    ├── templates
    │   └── photo_wall.html
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

path = "/opt/dashbea/TesteGSheet/core"
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin [CENSORED]
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName [CENSORED]
ServerAlias [CENSORED]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} [CENSORED] [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [CENSORED] [R,L]

<Directory /var/www/html/>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin [CENSORED]
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
#ServerName [CENSORED]
ServerName [CENSORED]
#ServerAlias [CENSORED]
#ServerAlias [CENSORED]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} [CENSORED] [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [CENSORED] [R,L]

#Alias /dashboardteste/ /[CENSORED]
#Alias /static/ [CENSORED]
#Alias /images  "/var/www/html/static/"

#<Directory [CENSORED]
#    Require all granted
#</Directory>

# Executar o Django como usuario apache
SuexecUserGroup [CENSORED] [CENSORED]
#Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

        <Directory [CENSORED]>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Order deny,allow
                        Allow from all
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

# Certificados TLS/SSL
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile [CENSORED]
SSLCertificateKeyFile [CENSORED]
#SSLCertificateChainFile [CENSORED]

WSGIScriptAlias /dashbea [CENSORED]/core/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess core python-home=[CENSORED]/my_env python-path=[CENSORED]/TesteGSheet
WSGIProcessGroup core

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</VirtualHost>
```

I have succesfully implemented the Tom Dekan Tutorial in a local machine, but have failed to implement it in the server.

Comment: I found this from github (note that this isn't sort of promotion) that you can try loading your credentials like the sample below:

credentials_dict = json.loads(content)

credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
    credentials_dict["token"],
    refresh_token = credentials_dict["refresh_token"],
    token_uri = credentials_dict["token_uri"],
    client_id = credentials_dict["client_id"],
    client_secret = credentials_dict["client_secret"],
    scopes = credentials_dict["scopes"])

https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/issues/253